# Statements related to Thurston's work on the surface

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, intersection-theory

If we have simple closed curves $\alpha$ and $\beta$ on a surface $\Sigma_g$, the intersection number $i(\alpha ,\beta)$ is defined to be the minimal cardinality of $\alpha_1\cap\beta_1$ as $\alpha_1$ and $\beta_1$ range over all simple closed curves isotopic to $\alpha$ and $\beta$, respectively. We say $\alpha$ and $\beta$ intersect minimally if
$i(\alpha ,\beta) = |\alpha\cap\beta|\,$.

> How to see that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ intersect minimally if there are no pairs of $p,q\in\alpha\cap\beta$ such that the arc joining $p$ to $q$ along $\alpha$ followed by the arc from $q$ back to $p$ along $\beta$ bounds a disk in $\Sigma_g$?
> Maybe a sketch of the proof idea?

I think the converse is also true : "that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ intersect minimally only if there are no pairs of $p,q\in\alpha\cap\beta$ such that the arc joining $p$ to $q$ along $\alpha$ followed by the arc from $q$ back to $p$ along $\beta$ bounds a disk in $\Sigma_g$."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Untangling two simple closed curves on a surface](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371560/untangling-two-simple-closed-curves-on-a-surface)

Comment: A 2019 paper that may help: "Computing the Geometric Intersection Number of Curves," by Despré and Lazarus. In *Journal ACM*, 66, 6, Article 45 (Nov 2019). [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1145/3363367).

Answer (score 10):

This is called the "bigon criterion".  For a discussion, see Section 1.2.4 (and in particular Proposition 1.7) of the "Primer on mapping class groups" by Farb and Margalit.

The Google search "bigon criterion" also finds various references and lecture notes.  For example, here is the top hit:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646340/proof-of-the-bigon-criterion